# Geting a reference to a dialog window form (ShowMessage, MsgDialog etc)

Tags: delphi, events

Is there any event I could use so I'd catch the moment when `ShowMessage` appears on the screen? I'd also need pass a reference to the `TForm` which has shown the Message.

So far I tried `OnDeactivate`, but it seems, `ShowMessage` is not causing it...

In.NET there is methon on Application that catches every MessageBox (Application.AddFilterMessage or smth like this), I'd need something like this in delphi

**What I'm trying to achive is:**
I must catch the moment while a dialog window appears (or just a modal window, but it's not that comfortable). I need to do couple of instructions then. Goal of those instructions is to give me a refference to the just recieved DialogWindow so I could for example get a number of buttons that lies on it.

Comment: Although David's code may do what you want, my first thought is that you may be looking for a way to work around something. It may be that there's a better way, depending on why you need to do this. Is this a debugging step, a workaround for an errant 3rd party control, testing procedures, or something?

Comment: Maybe you can use [TApplication.OnModalBegin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TApplication.OnModalBegin) or [TApplicationEvents.OnModalBegin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents.OnModalBegin)?

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt I believe this is the best answer, for (apparently) Delphi 2010 and higher.

Comment: That OnModalBegin looks promising after first tests. You should post it as answer in case I'll make it work : )

Comment: OnModalBegin is not bad but it won't catch direct calls to show windows dialogs and it doesn't let the event handler know anything about the modal form that is being activated.

Comment: yeah, crap I need to get the bloody instance of the dialog window :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern Delphi versions, on modern Windows versions, `ShowMessage` results in a Windows dialog window. You can use a `WH_CBT` hook to catch the activation of that dialog window.

```
function CBTProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  wnd: HWND;
  ClassName: string;
begin
  if nCode=HCBT_ACTIVATE then
  begin
    wnd := wParam;
    SetLength(ClassName, 256);
    SetLength(ClassName, GetClassName(wnd, PChar(ClassName), Length(ClassName)));
    if (ClassName='#32770') or (ClassName='TMessageForm') then
      Beep;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Hook: HHOOK;
begin
  Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, HInstance, GetCurrentThreadId);
  if Hook=0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    ShowMessage('hello');
  finally
    if not UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```

Note that the actual window class name varies from system to system. On XP the class name will be `TMessageForm` because the dialog is actually a Delphi `TForm`. However, on Vista and later the dialog is a standard window message box dialog with window class name `#32770`.

I've shown this wrapped around a single call to `ShowMessage`, but you could install this at startup if you want to hook all message dialogs shown in your app.

Comment: Indeed I want to hokk all messages shown in my app. But I also need to get an instance of the dialogbox window. I've read that I can't get it using the handle

Comment: +1. `ShowMessage` (Dialogs) creates a window class `TMessageForm`. I also believe that you need to call `Result := CallNextHookEx` in `CBTProc`.

Comment: `#32770` class is create via `MessageBox` (Windows).

Comment: @JacekKwiecień The `wnd` local variable in the hook proc is the handle to the window being activated.

Comment: @David Heffernan I realise this might be a noobish question. I've created a test project with one form. I want all my communicates to be hooked. Where should I put the function CBTProc?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You can install the hook in your main form startup, so somewhere visible to that main form.

Comment: I put the function CBTProc in the main form unit. Then on FormCreate I called only Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, HInstance, 0); I also added a button calling ShowMessage. On click message is shown and then... my RAD Studio 2009 crashes without any prompt (yeah it literaly dissapears)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like passing 0 as the thread ID is not compatible with this type of hook. Use GetCurrentThreadId as in the answer. If you need to hook dialogs in other threads then you'll have to install in each thread, I think. By the way, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to catch instance of dialog window for further operations on it. I need to catch it every time  any dialog window appears in my app.

Comment: Then I think you will need to use a hook. It's the only way to catch a direct call to `MessageBox`, for example. On the other hand, if you are in charge of all the calls that show dialogs then you can call an app wide event handler at the point of call.

Comment: Ok lets assume I want to call a ShowMessage each time I get the ... ShowMessage (ok I know its dumb and my cause infinite loop but I just want to know how to use that hook of yours). How do I do that then? I got the function CBTProc declared and Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, HInstance, GetCurrentThreadId); on OnCreate of main form

Comment: That's not at all pleasant. You could use a thread local variable to disable the hook's processing so that you can call ShowMessage without causing recursive re-entrancy. I think it's time that you told us what your ultimate goal is with this and then we can maybe advise you of a better solution. I mean, my answer probably answers the question that you asked, but it does not feel very comfortable.

Comment: It's the `wnd` local variable as I said above. You are not going to get a `TForm` instance because a message dialog is not necessarily a `TForm`.

Comment: You are not going to find a VCL form because `wnd` is not a VCL form. It's a windows dialog box. It's nothing to do with the VCL. If you want to work with `wnd` then you will need to use raw Win32 API calls.

Comment: It seems, your answers solves my problem. Too bad it creates another one. Now I need to operate on a Windows dialog box, which I haven't done yet :/

Answer (score 5):

You can also use an application-wide hook installed in the main form's `OnCreate` event (uninstalled in `OnDestroy`):

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Application.HookMainWindow(ApplicationHook);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Application.UnhookMainWindow(ApplicationHook);
end;

function TMainForm.ApplicationHook(var Message: TMessage): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Message.Msg = WM_ENABLE) and not TWMEnable(Message).Enabled then // disabling
    for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
      with Screen.Forms[I] do
        if Enabled and (ClassNameIs('TMessageForm') or // ShowMessage, MessageDlg
          ClassNameIs('TForm') or // InputQuery
          ClassNameIs('TMyLoginDialog')) then // your own dialogs, etc.
        begin
          Screen.Forms[I].Position := poScreenCenter; // for example
          Result := True;
          Break;
        end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with modern Delphi. In modern Delphi `ShowMessage` results in a standard window message box and not a `TForm` descendent. But if you want to hook a `TForm` then this code looks good.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in Delphi XE2: `ShowMessage` and `MessageDlg` still use `TMessageForm`. You probably mean `MessageBox` API. This will not be included in `Screen.Forms` so you need a different strategy for this case.

Comment: Ah, that depends on the OS. On Windows v6 and later that is not so. I presume you are running on XP.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Comment: Are you running Windows classic theme? You only have to read the code to see what's going on. Look for `if TOSVersion.Check(6) and UseLatestCommonDialogs` in `Vcl.Dialogs.pas`. As it stands you code cannot work in some scenarios.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I'm using the Classic theme. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Likewise thanks for pointing out that my code would not work on XP and Classic theme. I've fixed that now but I think that the approach outlined here simply cannot be made to work with windows dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use OnActiveFormChange?

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ScreenActiveFormChange;
end;

procedure TForm3.ScreenActiveFormChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Screen.ActiveForm is TOKRightDlg then
    Screen.ActiveForm.Caption := 'Found';
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TOKRightDlg.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [TApplication.OnModalBegin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TApplication.OnModalBegin) and [TApplicationEvents.OnModalBegin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents.OnModalBegin). I haven't really tried them, so I can't comment on whether you can get the owner and/or the modal form inside these events.